Render paypal express button in jslayout
The goal is to render Paypal express button under the customer's email address field in checkout page.
Since the checkout page is render by jslayout, how can I insert the paypal express button block into an existing component. I have the following
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="paypal-express-button" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Tcs_OnePageCheckout/js/view/paypal-express-button</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>


                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>

Any idea on how to render paypal express button to the custom component that I created?

@Eric Libay
Hey,
```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.root">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.onepage" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="paypal-button" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Paypal/js/view/payment/paypal-express-button</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">paypal-express-button</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thank You!
